# Asyntask structure issue with json object

Tags: android, json

SOLVED : THE CODE THAT U NEED TO GET JSON OBJECT IN MAIN ACTIVITY IS

jsonObject[0] = new AsyntaskGetWeekFood(970305).execute().get();
IN TRY CATCH

I have made an Asynctask class

```
int date ;
private Context context;

public AsyntaskGetWeekFood(Integer week) {
    this.date = week ;

}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    JSONObject jsonfood = new JSONObject();
    Document document = null;
    try {
        document = Jsoup.connect("http://self.shahroodut.ac.ir/Ghaza.aspx?date=" + date).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        Element sob = document.select("#BulletedListC" + i).first();
        Element shab = document.select("#BulletedListS" + i).first();
        try {
            jsonfood.put("c"+i,sob.text());
            jsonfood.put("s"+i,shab.text());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return jsonfood;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
}
```

How can I return the jsonfood to main activity class ?
I have debuged and my jsonfood, contains data correctly how to give that json object in main activity?...pls help me!

Comment: can you show the error you are getting?

Comment: @ADM hi i have edited the last line of my question ..pls read

Answer (score 0):

Ok it is your postExecute code

```
@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
super.onPostExecute(jsonObject) };
```

Now you can declare an interface

```
interface GetData { void onGetData(JsonObject object);}
```

Now you can reference it and set value in `postExecute` method
Like: `@Override
     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    mGetData.onGetData(jsonObeject)};`

And you have to implement the interface in your UI class.

Comment: how can do this in main activity class?? i am new to programing pls write the mainActivity code